# Industry approved set of template for both technical design and requirement gathering (IIBA, PMI, etc.)?

Tags: templates

I am the Product Manager at a small startup, and I am trying to find a good set of templates to use for our design team.  There are so many different variants out there, but I'd like something that I can standardize against. Obvious ones would be the IIBA and PMI templates, but they are more for Project Managers and pure BAs (very useful, but I need something more technical).  I know back in my days at Nortel Networks, we used to do Design Specification Documents (DSDs), but I think it was just some cobbled together doc that someone made.

Can anyone point me in the right direction towards a set of "industry approved / accepted / recommended templates that I can use"?  Something related to Architectural and Requirements that has boilerplate content that I just replace.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the best answer.  The best templates are to go to the source.  PMI and IIBA:

- https://stlouis.iiba.org/template-library
- https://www.projectmanagement.com/Templates/index.cfm